# Finding the longest path in a complete directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, longest-path

I was thinking on how to find a longest possible path in a complete, directed graph for every single vertex.
[Example of such a graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64X5t.png)

So for every single vertex I want to find the maximum possible amount of vertices that one can travel through (not going through any vertex more than once) and the specific path that has that specific length.

For example in the given graph, for starting vertex nr.1, the maximum length is 4 and the path:
1,4,2,3 ,or 1,2,3,4 (I just need to get one of them, not all).

What kind of algoritm could handle that?

In case it matters I use C++.

Comment: The first thing to realise about this problem is that it's NP-hard, so if you come up with a better-than-exponential-time algorithm, you'll win a million dollars.

Comment: @j_random_hacker But Floyd–Warshall algorithm solves all pairs shortest paths in O(n^3), i think we can do the same but for longest path with the same complexity , right ?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb: Nope, longest path (also known as "Hamiltonian Path") is NP-hard.  If you have a shortest path from u to v, then every subpath of it from u to x is necessarily a *shortest* path from u to x, enabling a shortest path from u to v to be efficiently built up from smaller shortest paths -- but the same is not true if we replace "shortest" with "longest", in particular because these longest subpaths will in general use many of the same vertices, so joining them together produces a path that is no longer simple.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Wow explained very well, thanks I got it now.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb: Thanks :)  It's certainly surprising that such similar-seeming problems can be so different from each other in terms of solution difficulty.

Comment: @j_random_hacker so how would you sugest solving it in polonomial time? NP hard should be enough for small amounts of vertices (less than 10).

Comment: @GraphLearner You can do a dfs from each node and find the longest path in O(n) and use a mask to mark visited vertexes during the dfs.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Can it also work with BFS?

Comment: @GraphLearner yes definitely.

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb Thank you!!!

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb: This will work provided that you backtrack, i.e., try *every possible* unvisited neighbouring vertex as the next vertex.  Maybe that's what you meant by "dfs", but usually that term is reserved for an O(|V|+|E|)-time algorithm that visits each edge and vertex at most once.